# msgbox when user hits enter in visual basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I just want to alert when user hit "enter" key.

I tried this one in keyup event,

```
If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
    MsgBox("msg")
End If
```

It didnt work, is that wrong ?

Comment: In which event handler did you put that code?

Comment: i put that in Form1_KeyUp, Keypress, Keydown none of the worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Enter key has strictly defined use in UI design, it executes the "accept" action of a dialog.  In the designer, select the form and set the AcceptButton to your button.  No code is required.

Note that the CancelButton has a similar usage, it is hard-wired to the Escape key.

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer but it may help. You may block Submission of the main form by exiting sub in case that another textBox is active:

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click

        ' do not submit anything in case that something else is active
        If txtItemPrompt.Focused() Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        ' rest of the code
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what context you are applying to. The KeyUp event will only fire on a particular control, and bubble up to it's parent controls. However, if focus is not set on the control you are handling the event on then the event will not fire.

Comment: actually there is just a button on my form, and i just want to handle enter hits to that button, it should be easiest :

Answer (score 0):

Just need to makes sure you put the code inside a sub that Handles Me.KeyDown

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            MsgBox("Enter Pressed")
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: yeah i did that, no luck, there must be sth missing

Comment: I created a new project  with the code above and it worked fine.

Do you have any other code in the page that could be capturing the same event?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the keypreview property of your form to true if you want to see the enter key at the form level.  Otherwise it is consumed by whatever control has focus.